# Matlab: How to set the feedthrough characteristic in n4sid function for MIMO system identification?

Tags: feed-forward, system-identification

I have a question regarding the feedthrough option in the `n4sid` function for subspace identification. According to the MathWorks help, `'Feedthrough'` should be specified as a logical vector of length *Nu*, where *Nu* is the number of inputs. For example for a system with 2 inputs and one output, we can use `n4sid` as:

```
[sys,x0] = n4sid(data,model_order,'Ts',0,'DisturbanceModel','estimate','Feedthrough',true(1,2));
```

However, when working on MIMO systems, The *D* matrix is *Ny* by *Nu* where *Nu* and *Ny* are the number of inputs and outputs, respectively. For specifying `'Feedthrough'` option, I expect to specify a *Ny*Nu* matrix, not a *1*Nu* vector.

When I use a matrix instead of a vector, I get an error that the feedthrough must be set as a vector. In fact, it is quite possible that the feedthrough from input *Ui* to the output *Yj* be zero, whereas the feedthrough from the very *Ui* to another output (e.g., *Yk*) be non-zero. In other words, the entries of the *D* matrix can be zero or non-zero independent of other entries of the *D* matrix. If we specify a vector for feedthrough, we are implicitly saying that all the feedthroughs from one input to all outputs are zero or all are non-zero together. Does anybody have an idea about this?